# Why is this function call not working using Coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm now making the transition towards writing all my javascript code using Coffeescript, But I'm frustrated because the simplest of examples is causing me problems. As of now, I've done more than an hour of research without being able to find the answer to this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link href="sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/coffeescript">
    $ ->
      sayHi()

    sayHi = ->
      alert 'Hi there!'
  </script>
</head>    
<body>
  <div id="all">  
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

As it is clear from the code above, I'm just trying to make the call to the **sayHi()** function work from inside the jQuery's ready handler. But the error I'm getting is the following:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Please help me, According to the compiler and tutorials I've read this '*should*' work, But I don't know what I'm doing Horribly wrong for this to not run :(

Comment: Last time I checked, browsers don't have CoffeeScript interpreters... or is that "coffee-sript.js" script translating the CoffeeScript code into JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried flipping the two statements? I've never worked with CoffeeScript but I'm assuming it's due to the fact that you're calling a method/function before it's been defined (like back in C)

Comment: @Šime Vidas Which means that what I'm doing wrong is.... ?

Comment: @Babak Naffas Spot on! That made it work (flipping the statements). I first declared the function, then just below, the ready handler. However.. That arises a new question.. Why is it like this? pure JS doesn't seem to enforce this requirement.

Comment: @user766388 ... placing the CoffeeScript code inside a `<script>` element of a web-page.

Comment: user766388, looks like @Squeegy understands this quite well.

Comment: @Babak Naffas yeah, he sure does, I'll review his answer now, (I was at lunch break sorry)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`text/coffeescript` tags have a key difference from `text/javascript` tags.  They dont "run" until the document loads.  This is because the coffee script library has to find all the coffee script tags and compile them, and it has to wait until the DOM ready so it can be sure to find them all.

The other issue is that jQuery will fire the DOM ready callback immediately if the event already happened.  And in this case it has.

So when this is compiled to JS you get this:

```
var sayHi;
$(function() {
  return sayHi();
});
sayHi = function() {
  return alert('Hi there!');
};
```

So what happens is:

- declare the `sayHi` variable with no value, making it `undefined`.
- Create the DOM ready callback for jQuery that uses this variable.
- jQuery runs the callback function immediately because DOM ready has already happened.
- The callback function executes, and tries to run `sayHi()` which is still undefined.
- After the callback runs, `sayHi` is then set to the function you wanted to run.

Now if this was a normal JS tag, it could have run before the document loaded, and then it would have worked fine because by time the callback actually ran, then `sayHi` would have been assigned properly.

To fix it you should assign the function BEFORE you run pass in the callback. Or you can skip doing the `$(->)` entirely since you know DOM ready fired already.  But really, this is one major reason you really shouldn't use coffeescript tags.  It's really not the same as using a JS tag.  And one of many reason this is not the recommended approach for using CoffeeScript on a real website.

So compile your coffee script before your browser sees it like a responsible developer :)

Comment: JavaScript, yes. But the browser CANNOT execute a coffee script tag, obviously. The coffee script library looks for all coffee script tags on DOM ready and compiles them, THEN runs them.  So if there is a `$(->)` in there it will run immediately.

Comment: So, when the browser encounters a `<script>` that has a type for which the browser doesn't have an interpreter, then the browser ignores that script. I see.

Comment: @Squeegy I TOTALLY agree with you. Things must be compiled, And I actually don't have to worry about it that much, since I work with rails, and the asset pipeline does wonders in this regard. The only reason I'm using the coffee tag was to test things out using a small example, And I'm actually glad I did, because otherwise I wouldn't have find out about this behavior. it's a great lesson and I thank you for it!

Answer (score 4):

Flip the statements. Looks like CoffeeScript has the same limitations as good old C where you can't make a call to a function/method until it has been defined in the order of your code.

So use

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  sayHi = ->
    alert 'Hi there!'

  $ ->
    sayHi()
</script>
```

Comment: You can, sorta.  It would have worked, except in this case the callback was running immediately. If it ran later on it would have worked fine.